# calling function from object, within another object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

i have a problem. I got a -> bmi: function(){with some code} - thats a function within an object(method). I want to declare it into another object, just with the name - bmi, so i dont repeat myself.

```js
var John = {
  fullName: "John",
  mass: 74,
  height: 1.75,
  bmi: function(){
    return this.mass / this.height + this.height;
  }
}

var Mike = {
  fullName: "Mike",
  mass: 90,
  height:1.95,
  John.bmi;
}
```

thats the code. I tried to declare it like that.

Comment: When declaring a key-value pair in an object literal, you need a key.

Comment: `bmi: John.bmi`. Although this isn't the preferred method..

Comment: solved my problem, but can you tell me why exactly that isn't preferred? Thank u :)

Answer (score 1):

Why not play nice and create a constructor function?

```
function Person(data){
   var self=this;
   self.fullName= data.fullName;
   self.mass= data.mass;
   self.height= data.height;
   self.bmi= function(){
        return self.mass / self.height + self.height;
    }

    return self;
}

var john = new Person({fullName : 'john', mass : 70, height: 1.70})
var marios = new Person({fullName : 'Marios', mass : 60, height: 1.70})

console.log(john.bmi())
console.log(marios.bmi())
```

Comment: Didn't learned about constructors yet, so i cant use them, but thank u :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var Mike = {
  fullName: "Mike",
  mass: 90,
  height:1.95,
  bmi: John.bmi;
}
```